# How to active Samsung S Health developer mode?

Tags: android

This is the Samsung Digital Heath ProgrammingGuide_SHealthService.pdf link
http://developer.samsung.com/html/techdoc/ProgrammingGuide_SHealthService.pdf

According to this guide document

> 3.3.1. S Health’s Developer Mode

Enable to active developer mode,
But in the S Health 5.4.1 version 
I can't find how to active developer mode.

Is anyone know how to active?

Answer (score 5):

Follow the below steps:

- Open S-Health App
- Go to Settings (Menu)
- In bottom of the screen you will find: About S-Health, Tap on it
- Now About S-Health Screen will open, and then tap 10 times on the version continuously.
- Now you will see Developer mode on the version line (where you tap 10 times).

Comment: Looks like you have experience with S-Health integration!

Comment: I still can't find about s-health in phone s health app...... is it S Health 5.4.1?

Comment: @khaki Will you able to find menu options in Setting (S-Health)?

Comment: @ManishJain I'm sorry I can't find Setting(S-Health)

Comment: @khaki  you have to open s health application and press capacitive menu button (if you have menu button on android phone) and there you will find settings menu.. and if you don't have a physical menu button (in case of devices running 5.0 or above) then you have to tap an icon on top-right side of toolbar in s health app. revert back with your findings.

Comment: @ManishJain I really appreciate your help, My s health version is over 5.0 so there is no physical menu button. but I don't know exactly what you saying that top-right side of toolbar. T T . In my case there is button to go my page in top-right side of main page.

Comment: did you implement it to get sleep hours ? I'm getting other things except sleep hours

Comment: @AnshulTyagi: you need to get permission for "com.samsung.health.sleep" in manifest file. And the remaining process is same as getting steps. You will get start time and end time in the dataset. Or You can start a new question as well and tag me their so we can discuss this.

Comment: Unfortunately I had to remove it because using that we cannot get BMI, heart rate and body temperature. Trying with Human API now 